# Garbage Collector and Core Foundation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation, garbage

I wrote a method for load Image into CALayer. This is the code:

```
- (CGImageRef)loadImage:(NSString*)path {
          // Get data image
          CGImageRef image = NULL;
          NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
          CFDataRef imgData = (CFDataRef)data;
          CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData (imgData);

          // Get CGImage from CFDataRef
          image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

          // If the image isn't a JPG Image, would be PNG file
          if (!image)
               image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

          return image;
}
```

I use this method in my CALayer:

```
NSString *pathString = // my image path;
aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.contents = [self loadImage:pathString];
```

It's work. I finalize my view (using garbage collector) but my application has leaks. Should I release CFDataRef imgData? I read that garbage collector does not work in Core Foundation.
Thanks and excuse my english.

Answer (score 3):

You are responsible for releasing this object by calling CGImageRelease.

See the documentation on garbage collection:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcCoreFoundation.html

> By default, therefore, in a garbage-collected environment you manage Core Foundation objects exactly as you would in a reference-counted environment (as described in Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation > “Ownership Policy”). If you create or copy a Core Foundation object, you must subsequently release it when you’re finished with it. If you want to keep hold of a Core Foundation object, you must retain it and again subsequently release it when you’re finished with it.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. How I should write finalize method? would this code be correct?: 

CGImageRelease(aLayer.content);
aLayer = nil

Comment: The contents is retained by the layer, so you can release it immediately after the aLayer.contents assignment. Keep in mind that you should not use a name like loadImage, but instead createImage, as you own the image that is returned (see Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation).

Answer (score 2):

the garbage collector *does* work with CoreFoundation types.

see CFMakeCollectable (excerpt from CF docs):

> CFTypeRef CFMakeCollectable(CFTypeRef
>   cf);
>
> Makes a newly-allocated Core
>   Foundation object eligible for garbage
>   collection.
>
> Parameters `cf` A CFType object to make
>   collectable. This value must not be
>   NULL. Return Value `cf`.
>
> Discussion For more details, see
>   Garbage Collection Programming Guide.